# Right way to update data in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

what is the right way in ReactJS to update and display the correct value.

Example: I show data on the screen from a database. When I change the values in the database I want to see the new values directly on the screen.

I have two files:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        containers: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;

    axios.get('http://reactlaravel.dev/container/count').then(function (response) {
        self.setState({
            containers: response.data
        });
    })
}

render() {
    const containers = this.state.containers.map( (container, i) => <StockCount key={i} {...container} /> );

    return (
        <div>
            {containers}
        </div>
    )
}

const Container = ({ name, total, current }) => (
<div>
    <span>{name}</span>
    <span>{total}</span>
    <span>{current}</span>
</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And the second file:

```js
export class StockCount extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const currentBar = this.props.current;
        const totalBar = this.props.total;
        const progressBar = currentBar / totalBar * 100;

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>{this.props.current} - {this.props.total} -  {this.props.name}</h1>

            <div className="progress">
                <div className={progressBarType} role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={progressBar} aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style={style}>
                    <span className="sr-only">{progressBar}% Complete (success)</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: *When I change the values in the database I want to see the new values directly on the screen* - what, you mean without refreshing the page or?

Comment: Yes. When I change data from the database I will see this after a page change. But with ReactJS you want to see change without refreshing the page.

Comment: All you can do is to re-fetch the data every X seconds. Otherwise it's not really possible. There are database engines out there to which you can subscribe to and listen when they trigger an event, but I don't know how practical this option is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement server push (will require server changes) in order to notify client app about database changes. Here is easiest way to go without server modifications **short pulling**:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.lookupInterval = setInterval(() => {
     axios
        .get('http://reactlaravel.dev/container/count')
        .then(function(response) {
        this.setState({
            containers: response.data,
        })
        })
  }, 500)
}
componentWillUnMount() {
    clearInterval(this.lookupInterval)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The interval is working correctly. Is this also a correct way to continuously retrieve data from a database with ReactJS?

Comment: React is just about rendering, and it not care about how data will be retrieved. In other words, you can do what ever you want about data fetching. I'v just showed simplest example, and any other methods wouldn't be be more or less correct

Answer (score 0):

Use a life cycle method for updating? like componentWillReceiveProps() https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html